# удаление и добавление html при ресайзе страницы с помощью jquery

Tags: html, jquery

пытаюсь манипулировать DOM при ресайзе с помощью такого кода

```
 $(window).resize(function() {

            var windowWidth = $('body').innerWidth();
            var elem=$('.Head').append();
            if(windowWidth < 450){
                if(elem.length<1){
                    $('.Head').append('<--->')
                  }
                $('.rem').hide();
            }
            else{
               $('.Add').hide();
               $('.rem').show();
            }


});
Но при изменении размера страницы без перезагрузки часть кода не выполняется,пожалуйста подскажите как сделать правильно
```

вот сайт для большей наглядности http://f0236766.xsph.ru/

Answer (score 2):

Заверните все в

```
$( window ).resize(function() {

});
```

Comment: спасибо,помогло!

Comment: можете еще подсказать почему не выполняется это условие ($('.append').length<1) и вот это  $('.append').remove();? сайт я обновил

Comment: у вас нет элементов `.append`, чтобы что-то удалять. Исходя из прошлого суждения условие всегда `true` - выполняется когда ширина окна меньше 450 (вы сами указали)

Comment: я изменил код в своем вопросе, но теперь это if(elem.length<1) условие не выполняется , подскажите что я не так делаю,пожалуйста